# Struts 2 access request.isUserInRole

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, struts2, jboss, roles

I'm developing a small Java EE application using Struts 2 and Rest Services over a JBoss AS7 server.

I'm using FORM auth for REST and Web content, and I don't have any problem with REST, but on the web, I have to distinguish between `"manager"` and `"admin"` roles in order to show some extra options to admin users.

I'd like to do something like:

```jsp
<s:if test="#request.isUserInRole("admin")>
```

but it doesn't work.

Do you know any way so I can achieve something like this? How do I should distinguish between roles in my JSP pages?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`PrincipalAware`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/PrincipalAware.html) to implement it by the action used to render the JSP. When you implement it in the action Struts2 injects [`PrincipalProxy`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/PrincipalProxy.html) object to your action. Ensure [`servlet-config` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/servlet-config-interceptor.html) is applied to the action.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements PrincipalAware {

  protected PrincipalProxy principal;

  public void setPrincipalProxy(PrincipalProxy principalProxy) {
    this.principal = principalProxy;
  }

  public PrincipalProxy getPrincipal() {
    return principal;
  }
}
```

This object then you could find in the `valueStack` on the JSP page and do something like

```
<s:if test="principal.isUserInRole('admin')">
```

You could also access this information from [How do I obtain security details (JAAS).](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14239)

Comment: The problem of using this is that I need to implement PrincipalAware and inject PrincipalProxy in all my Actions, because I need to check roles in all my JSPs. It's a valid option, but I think it will make my code messier in my Actions.

Comment: @Pablo, simply do it in a PabloBaseAction, and make the other actions extend it instead of directly extend ActionSupport... no mess, just Inheritance :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on this way:

importing:

```
<jsp:directive.page import="com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack"/>
<jsp:directive.page import="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext"/>
<jsp:directive.page import="org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext"/>
```

then stacking request with:

```
<jsp:scriptlet><![CDATA[
ValueStack stack = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();
 stack.set("httpServletRequest", ServletActionContext.getRequest());
]]></jsp:scriptlet>
```

and to check roles:

```
<s:if test="httpServletRequest.isUserInRole('admin')">
```

Comment: Good question but very ugly solution.